# Magento admin issue

Tags: magento

Hi I'm creating my first admin section for my extension. I've created a menu which links to a page displaying a grid. The problem is when you click through to edit the record, its displaying this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/theBookClub/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php on line 129

For the life of me I can't see any reference in any of the relevant files

```
class Namespace_Bookshelf_Block_Adminhtml_Bookshelf_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
   public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->_objectId = 'id';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'bookshelf';
    $this->_controller = 'bookshelf_admin';
    $this->_mode = 'edit';

    $this->_addButton('save_and_continue', array(
              'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Save And Continue Edit'),
              'onclick' => 'saveAndContinueEdit()',
              'class' => 'save',
    ), -100);
    $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('bookshelf')->__('Save Example'));

    $this->_formScripts[] = "
        function toggleEditor() {
            if (tinyMCE.getInstanceById('form_content') == null) {
                tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'edit_form');
            } else {
                tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'edit_form');
            }
        }

        function saveAndContinueEdit(){
            editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/');
        }
    ";
}

public function getHeaderText()
{
    if (Mage::registry('example_data') && Mage::registry('example_data')->getId())
    {
        return Mage::helper('bookshelf')->__('Edit Example "%s"', $this->htmlEscape(Mage::registry('example_data')->getName()));
    } else {
        return Mage::helper('bookshelf')->__('New Example');
    }
}
```

and this

```
class Namespace_Bookshelf_Block_Adminhtml_Bookshelf_Grid extends                Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('bookshelf_grid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('bookshelf_id');
    $this->setDefaultDir('desc');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
}

protected function _prepareCollection() {
    $collection = Mage::getModel('bookshelf/bookshelf')->getCollection();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns() {
    $this->addColumn('bookshelf_id', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('bookshelf')->__('ID'),
        'align' => 'right',
        'width' => '50px',
        'index' => 'bookshelf_id',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('customer_id', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('bookshelf')->__('Name'),
        'align' => 'left',
        'index' => 'customer_id',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('bookshelf_name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('bookshelf')->__('Name'),
        'align' => 'left',
        'index' => 'bookshelf_name',
    ));



    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}





public function getRowUrl($row) {
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
}
```

}

and this

```
class Newdaymedia_Bookshelf_Block_Adminhtml_Bookshelf extends
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
public function __construct()
{
$this->_controller = 'bookshelf_admin';
$this->_blockGroup = 'bookshelf';
$this->_headerText = Mage::helper('bookshelf')->__('Item Manager');
$this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('bookshelf')->__('Add Item');
parent::__construct();
}

protected function _prepareLayout()
 {
   $this->setChild( 'grid',
       $this->getLayout()->createBlock( $this->_blockGroup.'/' . $this->_controller . '_grid',
       $this->_controller . '.grid')->setSaveParametersInSession(true) );
   return parent::_prepareLayout();
 }
}
```

Any help would be gratefully received!

NEW

```
class Namespace_Bookshelf_Block_Adminhtml_Bookshelf_Edit_Form extends     Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getExampleData())
    {
        $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getExamplelData();
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getExampleData(null);
    }
    elseif (Mage::registry('example_data'))
    {
        $data = Mage::registry('example_data')->getData();
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array();
    }
    Mage::log("this is the form class");
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
            'id' => 'edit_form',
            'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
            'method' => 'post',
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ));

    $form->setUseContainer(true);

    $this->setForm($form);

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('example_form', array(
         'legend' =>Mage::helper('bookshelf')->__('Example Information')
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('name', 'text', array(
         'label'     => Mage::helper('bookshelf')->__('Name'),
         'class'     => 'required-entry',
         'required'  => true,
         'name'      => 'name',
         'note'     => Mage::helper('awesome')->__('The name of the example.'),
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('description', 'text', array(
         'label'     => Mage::helper('bookshelf')->__('Description'),
         'class'     => 'required-entry',
         'required'  => true,
         'name'      => 'description',
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('other', 'text', array(
         'label'     => Mage::helper('bookshelf')->__('Other'),
         'class'     => 'required-entry',
         'required'  => true,
         'name'      => 'other',
    ));

    $form->setValues($data);

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

}

Comment: Most likely the first file you listed has the issue, an inheritance issue perhaps, as setData() doesn't appear to be defined, my guess is in the `getHeaderText` method. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a helper created for your module (even if it does nothing). In your module's helper directory create a file called Data.php and create a class in there called Namespace_Module_Helper_Data that extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract.

I think that should help clear the problem up.

Comment: Unfortunately I already have a helper for my extension, got no idea whats causing this issue.

Comment: What is at  line 129 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/theBookClub/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php?

Comment: its this line $this->getChild('form')->setData('action', $this->getSaveUrl());

Comment: Check out layout file for your module. For some reason it is looking for a child element called form. I would bet there is an element named "form" but the block type for it does not map to a valid class , or there is not a child element called form.

Comment: It turns out I forgot to add the form block - so I did and its still getting the same error. I've added the form block class above

Comment: I am getting the same error but wondering why have you marked it green , you have not told the solution?

Answer (score 7):

This might solve your issue:

In your form container class:

```
Namespace_Bookshelf_Block_Adminhtml_Bookshelf_Edit 
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
```

If you add these test lines, you'll see which Form class Magento is trying to load

```
$form_block = $this->_blockGroup . '/' . 
              $this->_controller . '_' . 
              $this->_mode . 
              '_form';
echo $form_block;
```

For this to work with your code (above), your class:

```
Namespace_Bookshelf_Block_Adminhtml_Bookshelf_Edit_Form
```

should echo a test value of:

```
bookshelf/adminhtml_bookshelf_edit_form
```

and should be in the following filepath:

```
app/code/local/Namespace/Bookshelf/Block/Adminhtml/Bookshelf/Edit/Form.php
```

You might have to adjust the class name(s), or the filepath, or both, in order to get it working.

Good luck!

Comment: Adding the Form.php class did the trick for me. This should be marked as the answer.

Comment: Keep in mind to also check for typos as they can be easy to overlook. If you're positive the block class alias is correct, double check things like `$this->_blockgroup` vs `$this->_blockGroup`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Adminhtml controller is under
Namespace/ModuleName/controllers/Adminhtml/BookshelfController.php

try $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_bookshelf'; on Your Form Container.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to clarify that $this->_controller is not the actual controller name but the block class name and $this->_blockGroup is actually the module name.

so try:

> $this->_blockGroup = 'namespace_bookshelf';
>
> $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_bookshelf';